# Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

Tags: php

Been banging my head on a wall for a while.  I read through most of the suggested questions too.  I am trying to pass my mysqli connection into the class contructor and set it to a class variable and am getting: Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

PHP:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("abc", "abc", "abc", "abc");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MariaDB: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
/* check connection */
if ($con->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $con->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$t = new Timer($con);
// lots of irrelevant code
unset($t);

class Timer {
    private $time = null;
    private $con;
    public function __construct($con) {
        $this->$con = $con;
        $this->time = time();
        echo 'Working - please wait..<br/>';
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        $basename = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        $query = "SELECT ScriptID FROM scripts WHERE `ScriptURL` = '$basename';";
        $scriptIDResult = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, $query)) or die(mysqli_error($con));
        $t->scriptID = $scriptIDResult['ScriptID']; 
        $elapsed = (time()-$this->time);
        echo '<br/>Job finished in '.($elapsed).' seconds.';
        $scriptQuery = "UPDATE `scriptruns` SET `ScriptExecutedTime` = '$elapsed', `ScriptRunDate` = NOW() WHERE `ScriptID` = '$scriptID'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $scriptQuery) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    }
}
```

Error is being thrown in the construct function on: `$this->$con = $con;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
$this->$con = $con;
```

It is just a typo but let's see what happens. `$this->$con` is the property of `$this` whose name is stored in the `$con` variable. Looking for  a name, PHP tries to convert `$con` to a string; `$con` is an object of class `mysqli` (that doesn't implement `__toString()`) and this is why it triggers the *"Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string"* error message.

Obviously, the code should read:

```
$this->con = $con;
```

---

You will also get errors in `__destruct()`. The variable `$con` you use like a `mysqli` object is not set. It should be `$this->con` everywhere in the destructor.